# Javascript is not working in this code

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I tried to execute this, without loading the alert message, straight away it navigates to homeNew.aspx page. But when the redirection code is not available, the alert message is popping up correctly... I need both function that means after clicking "ok" to the alert message It should be redirected to next page.. Please help me to overcome from this problem.

```
if (TextBox2.Text == nic)
{
    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Check your email to retrieve your user name and password!')</script>");
    Response.Redirect("homeNew.aspx");
    connection.Close();
}
else
{
    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('INVALID Email address and NIC combination, Try Again!')</script>");
}
```

Comment: change TextBox2.Text == nic to TextBox2.Text == "nic"

Comment: nic may be a parameter and not a string literal.

Comment: nopes nic is a variable no problem in it, As I told response.write statement & response.redirect status are not working when both are there only response.redirect is working. If I dnt have that statement in that case response.write statement is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Because the redirection, the java script you coded isn't run by the browser.
You may code the redirection code inside your javascript.

```
if (TextBox2.Text == nic)
{
    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Check your email to retrive your user name and password!'); window.location=""/homeNew.aspx""</script>");
}
else
{
    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('INVALID Email address and NIC combination, Try Again!')</script>");
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot SuperLucky... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('Check your email to retrive your user name and password!');
window.location = '/homeNew.aspx';
```

You need to do both inside the script tag.